# How to append Urls in angular routing?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

How to do url(string) cocatenation in angular routing.

Please refer the below snippet to understand my question.

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$location'], function($routeProvider) {
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/AlbumsList.html',
    controller: 'a1Ctrl'
  }).
  when('/albums/:albumName', {
    templateUrl: 'AlbumsList.html',
    controller: 'b1Ctrl'
  })
})
app.controller('a1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.albums = function() {
    //ajax getting data from server 
  }
})

app.controller('b1Ctrl', function($scope, $routeProviders) {
  $scope.album = $routeProviders.albumName;

  $http({
    //same ajax function as above getting data from server for the nes sub album
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
      <a href="/albums/{{album.name}}">{{album.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Now when page is loaded, the first routing path is executed, the page is displayed as below 
[image: Output]

Now when I click the on say Hindi Albums  url in browser changes to /albums/hindi and html is rendered as below

[image]

Currently url in browser is getting updated to /localhost:8080/albums/himesh
Now my need is to update the url in browser to 
**/localhost:8080/albums/hindi/himesh**

So how to do such string concatenation using Angular routing.

Thanking You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `$routeProvider.when` url option, that will accept two parameter one would be `albumType` & other would be `alubmName`. You that you could get those values in your `b1Ctrl` using `$routeParams` service.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="album in albums">
  <a ng-href="/albums/{{alubm.type}}/{{album.name}}">{{album.name}}</a>
</li>
```

**Code**

```
when('/albums/:albumType/:albumName', {
    templateUrl: 'AlbumsList.html',
    controller: 'b1Ctrl'
})
```

Then inside your controller you should use `$routeParams` instead of `$routeProviders`.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('b1Ctrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.album = $routeParams.albumName;
  $scope.albumType = $routeParams.albumType; //alumType eg. hindi , english, etc

  $http({
    //same ajax function as above getting data from server for the nes sub album
  })
});
```